# Install OSX in VM in Bootcamp

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, boot-camp, window

I was wondering if it is possible to install OS X on a Virtual Machine in a Windows (Bootcamp) on a Mac?

Comment: Then install Parallels to go one level deeper.

Comment: It's OSception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible because of *Terms Of Use*. If you want a MacOSX virtual machine you need to run it from MacOSX. And I might be wrong, but I think it's only possible since OSX Lion.